# minimise the total distance to a hyperbolic curve from two fixed points

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

[image]

The point $C$ moves along the hyperbolic curve which is given by $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$.

The distances $d_{0}$ and $d_{1}$ in from $A$ to $C$ and $B$ to $C$ respectively.

How to find the point $C$ such that minimize the total length $d_{0}+d_{1}$?

Comment: The thing you're calling a "hyperbolic curve" isn't a curve; it's a surface. I don't think this changes the problem very much, though.

Comment: Calculation is difficult.

Comment: [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) are a possible way to solve your problem.

Comment: @Samprity Any thoughts?

Comment: I have tried with Lagrange Multiplier. Calculation is difficult. May be there are some tricks unknown to me. The problem can be arranged as a quadratic programming problem. But I have forgotten the subject.